# How to modify the layout of this graph?

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I have created a graph object, but I would like to choose the layout myself. The layout I have in mind is such that first nodes `F`s is placed at furthest left, then `DC`s and then `CC` and in the end `W`s in the furthest right. We can also put `DC`s and `CC` beside each other.
You can produce the graph by the following code:

```
graph_from_literal(F1--+DC1, F1--+DC2, F1--+DC3, F1--+CC, F1--+W1, F1--+W2, F1--+W3,
                   F2--+DC1, F2--+DC2, F2--+DC3, F2--+CC, F2--+W1, F2--+W2, F2--+W3, 
                   DC1--+CC, DC1--+W1, DC1--+W2, DC1--+W3, 
                   DC2--+CC, DC2--+W1, DC2--+W2, DC2--+W3, 
                   DC3--+CC, DC3--+W1, DC3--+W2, DC3--+W3, 
                   CC--+W1, CC--+W2, CC--+W3)
```

I tried the `layout` argument in `plot` function but the outcome is not what I have in mind. I would appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to customize your layered plot, we can try

```
# assign x-coordiates of vertices in terms of their names by following the desired order, i.e., from left to right
x_lo <- match(gsub("\\d", "", names(V(g))), c("F", "DC", "CC", "W"))

# assign y-coordinates uniformly within the range [-5,5] (grouped by `x_lo`), or we can also use random values if you like
y_lo <- ave(x_lo, x_lo, FUN = function(v) seq(-5, 5, length.out = length(v)))

plot(g, layout = cbind(x_lo, y_lo))
```

which gives

[image]

---

Another option might be using `layout_with_sugiyama`

```
plot(g, layout = -layout_with_sugiyama(g)$layout[,2:1])
```

and luckily we will obtain

[image]

Comment: Could an answer be anymore awesome Thomas?! No I highly doubt it. This is exactly what I was looking for, just could you please add some notes so that I know how you set them in the desired order.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR yes, thanks! I added some comments so hope it could help you to understand the idea.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for this brilliant and chic answer. I will review and ask any question further on.